# Magneto MFTF setup is not working/ Throwing error Could not find ActionGroup by ref "ResetAdminDataGridToDefaultViewActionGroup" in Element

Tags: magento2, mftf, api-functional-tests

I struck while setting up my MFTFframework in my local environment, your help is much appreciated.
I followed steps as per below url to setup MFTF but It is throwing error when i run **mftf generate:tests** as i mentioned below.

https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html

***! [NOTE] Could not find ActionGroup by ref "ResetAdminDataGridToDefaultViewActionGroup" in Element
!        "after"
C:\XAMPP\htdocs\mymagento2app\vendor\magento\module-adobe-stock-image-admin-ui\Test\Mftf\Test\AdminAd
!***        obeStockSaveLicenseWithSavedPreviewTest.xml
!***

Versions i used

Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1
Magento Functional Testing Framework CLI 2.6.5